# Forward compatibility between Python 3.5.2 and future versions

Tags: python, cmd

I am trying to use a piece of software that has been developed for use, specifically with Python 3.5.2. This version is no longer available. When running the setup batch file, I get a legacy-install-failure

'''

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  WARNING: No metadata found in c:\users\xo21065\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
  Moving to c:\users\xo21065\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages\scipy-1.8.0.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\xo21065\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\~cipy-1.8.0.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\xo21065\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages\scipy\
   from C:\Users\xo21065\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\~cipy
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> scipy
```

'''

I am struggling to find a suitable version of Python to see if this is a forward compatibility issue or something else?

Thanks

Comment: I guess your problem is with the version of scipy you are referring to. The latest version of scipy compatible with Python 3.5 is 1.4

Comment: The issue is with a 3rd party module, not the code itself. Later versions of Python should essentially be supersets of Python 3.5.

Comment: For clarification, the piece of code comes from the installation of the software I am trying to use. It requires explicitly Python 3.5.2, Scipy 1.1.0, and h5py 2.10.0. However, I am using Python 3.10 and all the current apps mentioned above. I cannot find Python 3.5, so I am using the most up to date version. Which I think is where all of these errors originate. Does anyone know where to find a usable version of Python 3.5.2?